# Serial и primary key в Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Хотел узнать чем отличается primary key от serial в СУБД Postgresql?
Serial - Это int + autoincrement.
Primary key - первичный ключ (обычно это id с типом int которое автоинкрементится) поэтому я вот и запутался немного.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё просто: между ними нет ничего общего.

`primary key` - это первичный ключ. Уникальный и обязательно `not null`, основной идентификатор записи с точки зрения теории реляционных баз.

`serial` - это синтаксический сахар над целочисленным типом данных, для которого создаётся счётчик `sequence` и ставится приращение этого `sequence` как `default` значение этого поля. `sequence` нетранзакционен и создаёт гарантированно не повторяющиеся числа в пределах этого sequence.

Впрочем, `serial` часто используют как суррогатный ключ модели данных и потому так же объявляют это поле первичным ключом, но это не обязательно. Они никак между собой не связаны, `serial` может не быть первичным ключом, первичный ключ может не быть `serial`

Comment: Спасибо большое, а можете добавить в ответ пример запроса на создание таблицы допустим со столбцами (id, name, surname) где id является автоинкрементируемым и он же первичный ключ, я просто никак не могу найти пример, как правильно это делать, заранее благодарю. То есть я делаю serial primary key, а в итоге он всё равно показывает ошибку

Comment: `create table tablename (id serial primary key);` Остальные поля добавить какие надо

Comment: Спасибо большо!